# PDO error on __construct when host is not rigth

Tags: php, pdo

I'm setting a wrong host just to test the exception error message but beyond that I'm getting another unexpected error.

**The host variable below does not exist**

```
try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host={$data['host']};dbname={$data['database']};charset={$data['charset']}", $data['user'], $data['password']);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    return $conn;
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

**Error**

```
Warning: PDO::__construct(): in  D:\xampp\htdocs\xuxuzinho\vendors\Xuxuzinho\lib\Database\Database.php on line 14 //I dont want this error
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Host not found.
```

The error on the second line is OK and what I want, but is there some way to suppress the warning I get in the first line?

Comment: Change your SQL host to IP address (e.g. 127.0.4.3) and see what will happen.

Comment: Now I understand. The host of the example is "localhosttt" so the warning is because the host is not on host format and dont because the host doesn't exists.. so the warning make all sense.. You helped me so if you formulate one answer I can accept this

Comment: I can't because the answer was redirected by jeroen. Anyway, you can mark my other comment as constructive, it would also help, thanks! :)